# Test on weak IV when first stage is nonlinear

Tags: instrumental-variables, 2sls

When the first stage is linear, like the case of 2sls, the test of weak IV is straight forward, method like **Stock and Yogo (2005) test** are available in standard package command, like `ivreg2` in Stata. But when I specify something nonlinear in the first stage (like a ordered probit model), the situation become complicated. Can I find some counterpart test for the nonlinear case, or I can specify a "linear" specification as the baseline (which I believe is problematic). Any suggestion is warmly welcome and literatures are desired, thanks in advance.

Comment: Non-linear 1st stage may not necessarily be a good idea. See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125830/consistency-of-2sls-with-binary-endogenous-variable