# 2SLS with a boolean regressor

Tags: regression, econometrics, probit, endogeneity, 2sls

So, I have the following linear model:
$$y = \alpha + \beta x + u$$
and $x \in \{0,1\}$, i.e. the variable $x$ is boolean. Moreover $x$ may be endogenous, and I have a set of instrumental variables $\boldsymbol{z}$ which are exogenous. In this situation usually one uses a simple 2SLS regression and that's it. But I was wondering whether one could first regress $x$ on $\boldsymbol{z}$ thorough probit, and then take the fitted values $\hat{x}$ as instrumental variables in the second step of the regression, where we use $\hat{x}$ as instrumental variable for $x$ and use IV.
So I have replaced the OLS regression of the first step with a probit regression.

Is the result of this kind of two step regression consistent? Does it make sense to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: These answers suggest that the answer is not generally yes: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94063/probit-two-stage-least-squares-2sls https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125830/consistency-of-2sls-with-binary-endogenous-variable

Comment: Angrist and Pischke section 4.6.1 is helpfull. Under the correct assumptions it can be shown in a GMM framework to be consistent and efficient to use the method you suggest. I ran a few numerical experiments which does not show a large efficiency gain so in any case I would follow the advice of Angrist and Pischke and stick with standard 2SLS.

Comment: have you ever found an answer? Cause I have a similar question?